# Blob metadata is not saved even though I call CloudBlob.SetMetadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

For a few hours I've been trying to set some metadata on the blob I create using the Azure SDK. I upload the data asynchronously using `BeginUploadFromStream()` and everything works smoothly. I can access the blob using its URI when the upload has completed, so it is created successfully, however **any metadata I set is not persisted**.

I set the metadata **after** calling `EndUploadFromStream()`.

I've tried setting the metadata the three ways I can find through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee773197.aspx):

```
// First attempt
myBlob.Metadata["foo"] = "bar";

// Second attempt
myBlob.Metadata.Add("foo", "bar");

//Third attempt
var metadata = new NameValueCollection();
metadata["foo"] = "bar";
blob.Metadata.Add(metadata);
```

After setting the metadata i call `myBlob.SetMetadata()` to save the metadata to Azure, as specified by the documentation, but it does not stick. The call **doesn't trow any exceptions**, but when I get a new reference to my blob, it **doesn't have any metadata**.

I've tried saving the metadata asynchronously as well using `BeginSetMetadata()` and `EndSetMetadata()` but with similar result.

I start to think I'm missing something really trivial here, but after staring at it for five hours, I still cannot understand where I go wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SetMetadata should work as expected. But simply getting a reference to the blob isn't sufficient to read the metadata.

After getting the blob reference, you need to call the [FetchAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee772829.aspx) method on that CloudBlob. This will load all properties and metadata, and only then will you be able to access the metadata you set previously:

```
// Get a reference to a blob.
CloudBlob blob = blobClient.GetBlobReference("mycontainer/myblob.txt");

// Populate the blob's attributes.
blob.FetchAttributes();

// Enumerate the blob's metadata.
foreach (var metadataKey in blob.Metadata.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Metadata name: " + metadataKey.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Metadata value: " + blob.Metadata.Get(metadataKey.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: As I suspected then, a really trivial thing! I guess I was too focused on the idea that writing was the problem - didn't even consider that the problem could be reading the properties. Thanks a lot, you saved my a bunch of time!

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question is quite old and in the meantime, I guess, the API has changed.

Now, if you want to fetch metadata then you need to use **BlobTraits.Metadata** option in the following snippet:

```
await foreach (BlobItem item in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.Metadata))
{
    var name = item.Name;
    var meta = item.Metadata;
}
```